# 2020 Moderator Election - Announcement

Tags: discussion, election

Buddhism Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **October 5** to bring in one more moderator.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on October 5, users can [nominate themselves](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On October 19, if there are two or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidate. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on October 20.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

The [nomination period for the 2020 election](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/election/1) was scheduled to end in 30 minutes. However, since we only had one candidate, I've extended the nomination period for another week.

On October 19, if there are two or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidate. (There's a small chance we'll need to remove a nomination, but I doubt that will come up.)

Answer (score 0):

*Sort uninvited, in trust that welcome, 'disturbing' the 'business as usual' to maybe giving it something special:*

The communities participants here are surely glad to get their manager known and may like it to send best greating to Brasil as well.

My person - since good manager Cesar is up to manage and possible not so familar - thought it would be good to introduce good householder to that of which is called merit-full, or good, for ones long term happines, as taught and practiced by the Buddha. At least it's good to known of what one possible manages to make ones things with care. Like if one would manage dangerous snakes, if not introduced well, although good thought, can lead to unpleasing accidents.

[Dez Maneiras de Praticar Mérito](https://sangham.net/pt/lib/authors/wijesinghe/punna)

May good householder's good undertakings always bear fruits quick an visible so that faith into focus on good deeds increase.

Much good success also here, since of either lot of merits or not so well.

[metta](https://sangham.net/en/dictionary/metta) & [mudita](https://sangham.net/en/dictionary/mudit%C4%81)

*[Note that this isn't given for stacks, exchange, other world-binding trades but for an escape from these looping games and end of suffering]*